# How to check back button pressed in startmenu folder page in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

```
var startmenu
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU DefaultPage $startmenu
```

In the above one line code can be used to create startmenu folder page.If the user click back button of this page want to move control some specific page.
I have tried `${NSD_Back}, OnClick` functions but i dont know where to implement this code to check back button pressed?

How to check back button pressed in the startmenu folder page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for does not make any sense but here you go:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
Var MyStartFolder
Var BackDetection
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE PageCallbackBeforeSMPre
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE PageCallbackSMPre
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU DefaultPage $MyStartFolder
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

# nsis.sf.net/Go_to_a_NSIS_page
Function RelGotoPage
IntCmp $R9 0 0 Move Move
StrCmp $R9 "X" 0 Move
StrCpy $R9 "120"
Move:
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT 0x408 $R9 ""
FunctionEnd

Function PageCallbackBeforeSMPre
${If} $BackDetection == "SM"
    StrCpy $BackDetection ""
    StrCpy $R9 -1
    Call RelGotoPage
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function PageCallbackSMPre
StrCpy $BackDetection SM
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Start menu page is created by third party plug-in, not by NSIS code.

So you need to modify Start menu plug-in sources to get notifications about.

Maybe if you say what are you trying to achieve we can help you?

There are plenty of other functions you can use - e.g. page's callback to check state of previous/next page.

Comment: ok..Thanks slappy.I want to check state of back button in the startmenu page? If the user click this button i need to do some action?.Is possible?

Comment: Possible - but only by rewriting the plug-in.